# sqlplus run in script gives error :Enter password: ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error Enter user-name:"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, sqlplus

I'm able to run sqlplus from the vscode powershell command line, but not in the script.  In the command line it connects and returns results.

This is what the command looks like (at command line, which works fine).

```
echo exit | sqlplus user/pw@RRRPRD.company.net:1521/RRRPRDC '@C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql'
```

It says this on the screen and all looks good:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

and it shows query results....
Then

```
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

I'm using VSCode now to run and work on the script.
This is the script:

...
$quote = '"'

$info = $("{0}/{1}@{2}:{3}/{4} ``@{5}{6}{5}" -f  $username, $password,
$hostIp, $port, $service,
$quote, $sqlPath,$quote)
$result = ""
Write-Host "info: $info"
$result = sqlplus '$info'
Write-Host "result: $result"

But it's showing an error when I print result:

```
info: user/pw@RRRPRD.company.net:1521/RRRPRDC `@"C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql"
result:  SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Jan 11 11:00:19 2022  Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.  Enter password: ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error   Enter user-name:
```

The query it's running now is

```
select * from tablename; quit;
```

which runs fine in Oracle sql developer and command line. This has a few columns and a few rows.

I'm not clear on why it's not running in vscode/debug mode, but it runs the command at the command line.  I've been fooling around with the backticks and it doesn't seem to make a difference for the error message running from vscode debugger.  I tried just copying the command to a string to run in the script, but it's tough to get the formatting right so the string terminates without error.

Any ideas why it won't run in the powershell script, but runs in the command line, and what to do to fix it?  I don't see anything online to fix this issue.

Update:
I'm seeing this [oracle home client][1], which seems similar, but isn't powershell. I'm not sure what I need to do for the fix they recommend.

Update: I did this at the command line and in the script:

(get-command sqlplus.exe).Path

and both print

C:\app\client\me\product\12.2.0\client_1\sqlplus.exe

Update2:

I’m told sqlplus location is different than oracle home client or the driver location used. I’m not sure about how to check/fix this.

echo $Env:Path at the vscode powershell prompt:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\app\client\me\product\12.2.0\client_1;C:\app\client\me\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\app\mcleary\product\12.2.0\client_1;C:\app\mcleary\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\DataDirect\Connect_for_ODBC_71\Drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\cteapis;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.3.0.0.0;C:\Users\me.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

echo $Env:Path running the script through vscode :
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\app\client\me\product\12.2.0\client_1;C:\app\client\me\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\app\mcleary\product\12.2.0\client_1;C:\app\mcleary\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\DataDirect\Connect_for_ODBC_71\Drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\cteapis;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.3.0.0.0;C:\Users\me.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[1]: https://gaurangpatel.net/tns-protocol-adapter-error-in-oracle

Comment: Double quotes are a pita with sqlplus on the command line. You need to wrap the `$password` once in `"` so that spaces in the password don't get parsed as multiple arguments, then you need to wrap that in `\"` because the oracle database requires double quotes on its side of the wire too; moreover, you can't `""` because that means `"` to the shell... which leaves you with  `sqlplus user/\""password"\"@service`

Comment: also note that your command line starts with `echo exit |` you probably want to change your short.sql file from a single line ending with `quit;` to `exit` on a second line